# How can I solve the problem of my quiz project?

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events

I've been working on this project for a while. I found the code from the Internet. I have never created a quiz game before. I edited the code a little. But unfortunately there are some problems with the code, which are difficult for me.

So far only digits are represented as questions. I want letters to be used for questions as well. The button to run the game, the limited reflection time and the score works. Unfortunately, if you press the right answer, the spear doesn't go on, but stops, but you get a point. I want that after a correct answer new questions are added and that the user gets a point. If the user presses the wrong answer, I want the game to stop and the scores achieved to be displayed.

```js
let playing=false;
let score=0;
let action;
let timeremain;
document.getElementById('start').onclick=function(){
    
    if(playing===true)
        {
           location.reload(); 
        }
    else
    {
        playing=true;
        document.getElementById('scoreValue').innerHTML = score ;
        document.getElementById('time').style.display="block"; 
        timeremain=60;
        genQA();
        document.getElementById('start').innerHTML="Reset Game";
       
        startCount();
    }
    
    
    
}


function startCount()
{
    
   action = setInterval(function(){
       timeremain -=1;
       document.getElementById('timeremain').innerHTML = timeremain;
       if(timeremain===0)
           {
               document.getElementById('time').style.display="none";
               gameOver();
           }
   },1000);
}


function gameOver()
{
    
    document.getElementById('gameover').style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('scoreno').innerHTML=score;
}

function genQA() {

    var x=Math.round(10*Math.random());
    var y=Math.round(10*Math.random());
    correctAnswer= x*y;
    document.getElementById('qtn').textContent=x +' x '+y;
    var correctPostion= 1+Math.round(3*Math.random());
    document.getElementById('option'+correctPostion).innerHTML=correctAnswer;

}


for(i=1;i<5;i++)
{
    document.getElementById('option'+i).onclick=function(){

        if(playing===true)
        {
            if(this.innerHTML==correctAnswer)
            {
                score++;
                document.getElementById('scoreValue').innerHTML = score ;
                hide('try');
                show('correct');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    hide('correct');
                },1000);
                
                genQA();
            }else{
                show('try');
                hide('correct');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    hide('try');
                },1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
body,html
{
    background-color: darkgray
}

.container
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 450px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 100px auto;
   /* margin-top: 150px;*/
    background-color: #9DD2EA;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 14px;
    position: relative;
}
#score
{
    
    border: 1px solid #3affa3;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #3affa3;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    left: 500px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#try
{
    border: 1px solid #f22929;
    background-color: #f22929;
    position: absolute;
    left: 260px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    color: aliceblue;
    display: none;
    
}
#correct
{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #f22929;
    background-color: #43f128;
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    color: aliceblue;
    
}
#qtn
{
     width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 50px auto 10px auto;
   /* margin-top: 150px;*/
    background-color: #80c3f7;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 14px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: cursive , sans-serif; 
    
}
#note
{
     width: 450px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto ;
   /* margin-top: 150px;*/
    background-color: #80c3f7;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 14px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: black;
}
.option
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 90px ;
    position: relative;
    transition:  all 0.12s;
}

#option1
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#option2
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 110px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#option3
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 220px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#option4
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 330px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
#start
{
     
     
    border: 1px solid #3affa3;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CEE9F5;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
    top: 440px;
    left: 280px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#option1:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option2:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option3:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option4:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option1:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
    top: 5px;
}
#option2:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
    top: 5px;
}
#option3:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
    top: 5px;
}
#option4:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    top: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
}


#start:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #9DD2EA;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#start:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
    top: 445px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px ;
}

#time
{
    width: 150px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: burlywood;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 450px;
    top: 440px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px ;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: none;
    
}
#gameover
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
 background-color: coral;
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    display: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 , user-scalable=yes" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"> 
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">

        <div id="correct">Correct</div>
        <div id="try">Try Again</div>
        <div id="score">
            SCORE:
            <span id="scoreValue">0</span>



        </div>
        <div id="qtn"></div>
        <div id="note">Click on the Right Answer</div>
        <div class="option">
            <div id="option1"></div>
            <div id="option2"></div>
            <div id="option3"></div>
            <div id="option4"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="start" class="box">Start Game</div>
      <div id="time">Time Remaing: <span id="timeremain">0</span></div>
        <div id="gameover">GAME OVER YOUR SCORE :<span id="scoreno">0</span></div>

    </div>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </div>

    </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: how about one question at a time.  What do you want to fix first?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the `show` and `hide` functions in your js (for starters).

Comment: I want first that it works like a quiz. Letters should also be used

Comment: `function genQA() {` generates the math quiz questions. There is currently no in-built provision for non-arithmetic questions.

Comment: Yeah! I see. How can I solve it? I woul like to do something like this:

Comment: question: 'What is 4 * 2?',
    answers: [
      { text: '6', correct: false },{ text: '16', correct: false },{ text: '60', correct: false },
      { text: '8', correct: true }
    ]

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your javascript code and i found some solutions .
This code will works for you . Its a little different : i corrected some errors .
I also added the classes for 'correct' and 'try' and modified the css file . 
Here you are your corrected codes :

---

Javascript code:

```
let playing=false;
let score=0;
let action;
let timeremain;
document.getElementById('start').onclick=function(){

if(playing===true)
{
location.reload(); 
}
else
{
playing=true;
document.getElementById('scoreValue').innerHTML = score ;
    document.getElementById('time').style.display="block"; 
    timeremain=60;
    genQA();
    document.getElementById('start').innerHTML="Reset Game";

    startCount();
    }
}


function startCount()
{

action = setInterval(function(){
   timeremain -=1;
   document.getElementById('timeremain').innerHTML = timeremain;
   if(timeremain===0)
       {
           document.getElementById('time').style.display="none";
           gameOver();
       }
   },1000);
}


function gameOver()
{

document.getElementById('gameover').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('scoreno').innerHTML=score;
}

function genQA() {

var x=Math.round(10*Math.random());
var y=Math.round(10*Math.random());
correctAnswer= x*y;
document.getElementById('qtn').textContent=x +' x '+y;
var correctPostion= 1+Math.round(3*Math.random());
document.getElementById('option'+correctPostion).innerHTML=correctAnswer;

}


for(i=1;i<5;i++)
{
document.getElementById('option'+i).onclick=function(){

if(playing===true)
{
if(this.innerHTML==correctAnswer)
{
score++;
document.getElementById('scoreValue').innerHTML = score ;
document.getElementById('try').innerHTML="" 
document.getElementById('correct').innerHTML="Correct";
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('correct').innerHTML=""; 
},1000);

     genQA();
     }else{
            document.getElementById('try').innerHTML="Try Again";
            document.getElementById('correct').innerHTML=""; 
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById('try').innerHTML="";
               },1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Css file :

```
body,html
{
background-color: darkgray
}

.container
{
width: 600px;
height: 450px;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 100px auto;
   /* margin-top: 150px;*/
background-color: #9DD2EA;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 15px;
box-shadow: -4px 4px 14px;
position: relative;
}
#score
{

border: 1px solid #3affa3;
font-size: 15px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #3affa3;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
left: 500px;
font-family:sans-serif;
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 8px;
}
#try
{
border: 1px solid #f22929;
background-color: #f22929;
position: absolute;
left: 260px;
padding: 3px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
color: aliceblue;
display: block;

}
#correct
{
display: block;
border: 1px solid #f22929;
background-color: #43f128;
position: absolute;
left: 250px;
padding: 3px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
color: aliceblue;

}
#qtn
{
 width: 450px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 50px auto 10px auto;
   /* margin-top: 150px;*/
background-color: #80c3f7;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 15px;
box-shadow: -4px 4px 14px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
font-size: 70px;
font-family: cursive , sans-serif; 

}
#note
{
 width: 450px;
height: 20px;
border: 1px solid blue;
margin: 10px auto 10px auto ;
   /* margin-top: 150px;*/
background-color: #80c3f7;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 15px;
box-shadow: -4px 4px 14px;
position: relative;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: black;
}
.option
{
position: relative;
margin-left: 90px ;
position: relative;
transition:  all 0.12s;
}

#option1
{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid white;
position: absolute;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
padding-top: 40px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
}
#option2
{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid white;
position: absolute;
left: 110px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
padding-top: 40px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
}
#option3
{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid white;
position: absolute;
left: 220px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
padding-top: 40px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
}
#option4
{
width: 100px;
height: 60px;
border: 1px solid white;
position: absolute;
left: 330px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
padding-top: 40px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;

}
#start
{


border: 1px solid #3affa3;
font-size: 15px;
position: absolute;
background-color: #CEE9F5;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px;
top: 440px;
left: 280px;
font-family:sans-serif;
padding: 3px;
border-radius: 8px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: sans-serif;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
#option1:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option2:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option3:hover
{
background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option4:hover
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#option1:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
top: 5px;
}
#option2:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
top: 5px;
}
#option3:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
top: 5px;
}
#option4:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
top: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px purple;
}


    #start:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
background-color: #9DD2EA;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px purple;
}
#start:active
{
   background-color: #9DD2EA;
top: 445px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px ;
}

#time
{
width: 150px;
height: 25px;
background-color: burlywood;
border: 1px solid;
position: absolute;
left: 450px;
top: 440px;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px ;
font-weight: bold;
display: none;

}
#gameover
{
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
 background-color: coral;
position: absolute;
top: 120px;
text-align: center;
padding: 100px;
font-size: 40px;
color: white;
display: none;

}
```

---

Html Page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Math Quiz</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 , user-                                   
scalable=yes" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"> 
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="container">

    <div id="correct" class="correct">Correct</div>
    <div id="try" class="try">Try Again</div>
    <div id="score">
        SCORE:
        <span id="scoreValue">0</span>



    </div>
    <div id="qtn"></div>
    <div id="note">Click on the Right Answer</div>
    <div class="option">
        <div id="option1"></div>
        <div id="option2"></div>
        <div id="option3"></div>
        <div id="option4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="start" class="box">Start Game</div>
  <div id="time">Time Remaing: <span id="timeremain">0</span></div>
    <div id="gameover">GAME OVER YOUR SCORE :<span id="scoreno">0</span></div>

</div>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

You only have to replace your files with this codes . 
I hope it helps you !   :-)

Comment: How can I change those questions form the quiz. i need some questions with words. You saved my day^^

Comment: I don't know . You should include a file in your html with a list of all the questions you want the quiz do. Usually i make a css file and i put in it the not supported files data .